# Languages for Bootstrap 3 selection change not working

Tags: jquery, ajax, selector

I am using  [Languages for Bootstrap 3](http://usrz.github.io/bootstrap-languages/), but I am not able to figure out how get the selected language using jQuery or even the span do not allow href ( I was using alert() to see the result).

Language selector is as follow:

```html
<div class="btn-group dropdown pull-right">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" >
    <span class="lang-sm lang-lbl-full" lang="en"></span> <span class="caret"></span>
  </button>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" >
    <li><span class="lang-sm lang-lbl-full" lang="ar" value="ar"></span></li>
    <li><span class="lang-sm lang-lbl-full" lang="en" value="en"></span></li>
    <li><span class="lang-sm lang-lbl-full" lang="fr" value="fr"></span></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Did you mean to use a select list? If you just want to use a span, you'll have to have an `onclick` function.

Comment: but how to get the clicked choice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create javascript to figure out what span has been clicked like so:

```
function ChangeLanguage(selected) {
    alert(selected.value()); // Do whatever you want in here.
}
```

and activate it like so:

```
<div class="btn-group dropdown pull-right">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" >
    <span class="lang-sm lang-lbl-full" lang="en"></span> <span class="caret"></span>
  </button>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" >
    <li><span class="lang-sm lang-lbl-full" onclick="ChangeLanguage(this)" lang="ar" value="ar"></span></li>
    <li><span class="lang-sm lang-lbl-full" onclick="ChangeLanguage(this)" lang="en" value="en"></span></li>
    <li><span class="lang-sm lang-lbl-full" onclick="ChangeLanguage(this)" lang="fr" value="fr"></span></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: alert(selected.getAttribute('lang'));